# zurb-foundation 5 data-interchange w/ xhtml

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 5 responsive pack , I would like to incorporate jsf and richfaces into my design. For the different screen sizes , is it possible to use jsf/ richfaces components embedded in xhtml for the data-interchange instead of just plain html and html elements?

WILL data-interchange[....] work with .xhtml ?

When I use  just basic html elements (no jsf or richface components) everything works as it should. I try to incorporate an xhtml with the following for example :

---

This doesn't work: larger_slider.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components">

<h:head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <div class="overlay2" style="text-align: center;">
        <h3>Safe. Fun. Online Streaming TV For Kids</h3>
        <h3>100% Free To Try. Let's Get Started!</h3>
        <div align="center" style="padding: 10px;">
            <a href="http://www.amebatv.com/watch/signup.jsf" class="large round button">Start Free Trial</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

---

This works:large_slider.html <--- note the html extension

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components">

<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <div class="overlay2" style="text-align: center;">
        <h3>Safe. Fun. Online Streaming TV For Kids</h3>
        <h3>100% Free To Try. Let's Get Started!</h3>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

---

```
Instead of this:
<div>
    data-interchange="[small_slider.html, (small)], [medium_slider.html, (medium)], [large_slider.html, (large)]">
</div>
```

I would like to do this: where xhtml contain a jsf richfaces form components

```
<div>
    data-interchange="[small_slider.xhtml, (small)], [medium_slider.xhtml, (medium)], [large_slider.xhtml, (large)]">
</div>
```

Comment: It'd be more helpful if you tell what problems exactly you're facing instead of asking a rhetorical question for which you would already easily figure out the answer by just running it yourself. All in all, I can't ignore the impression that you completely missed the point of XHTML. It enables web developers to use a XML based tool to produce HTML output. So, ultimately, both ways would still end up in some HTML content being served. The way how the server did that (either plain vanilla HTML, or via a XML tool) should be completely irrelevant to the client side.

Comment: @BalusC the problem is when I try to use xhtml with jsf/rich components they do not render. If I use just plain html and html components it works as it should.  Check the edits above.

Comment: In other words, `FacesServlet` isn't invoked? Did you make sure that the HTTP request URL matches the URL pattern in its servlet mapping? Or, from the other way on, did you make sure that the URL pattern in its servlet mapping matches the HTTP request URL? Using the JSF 2.x canonical URL pattern of `*.xhtml` should just do it. By the way, HTML doesn't have any concept of "components". It are called "elements".

Comment: I assume you are talking about :  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
     <url-pattern>/*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

Comment: @BalusC I added that to my web.xml . I am running JBOSS Runtime server 7.1 . The facesServlet works everyhwere else in the app, just not in the particular case.

Comment: I was talking about `FacesServlet`, not `DefaultServlet`. I was suggesting an URL pattern of `*.xhtml`, not `/*.xhtml`. Are you new to basic servlets? Explicitly re-mapping the container's default servlet in webapp's own `web.xml` is also a very poor practice. Try to not shoot in the dark by randomly copypasting snippets you found elsewhere on the internet, but try to actually understand what exactly those code lines do. This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: @BalusC Thank you. I will take a deeper look at the resource you provided.

Comment: @BalusC Did some digging the problem still persists. Even if I strip my xhtml down to nothing except bare bones not thing is shown.data-interchange refuses to work .xhtml extensions. It only works with .html extensions.  data-interchange="[small_slider.html, (small)], [medium_slider.html, (medium)], [large_slider.html, (large)]">

Comment: That will indeed happen if the `FacesServlet` is not invoked. It's the one reasponsible for producing the right HTML output based on XHTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

```
  <div>
      data-interchange="[small_slider.xhtml, (small)], [medium_slider.xhtml, (medium)], [large_slider.xhtml, (large)]">
    </div>
```

I used :

```
  <div>
      data-interchange="[small_slider.jsf, (small)], [medium_slider.jsf, (medium)], [large_slider.jsf, (large)]">
   </div>
```

Works like a charm now.

Comment: In other words, your `FacesServlet` was being mapped on an URL pattern of `*.jsf`, not `*.xhtml`.

Answer (score 0):

Are your richfaces components, getting data from Java Managed Beans working fine with Zurb foundation in the picture ?